# Why nested for loop is not working Python?

Tags: python, for-loop

The outer foor loop is executing onl one time. I can not detect the problem why this is happeding?

```
f=open("simpletextfile.txt")
for r in range(1,52):
    for line in f.readlines():
        print r
```

where `simpletextfile.txt` contains the message `This a message!!`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is exhausted after you call `readlines`, as in subsequent calls to `readlines` will not read more lines as all the lines have been read. The inner loop with then execute but have nothing to do. If you want to read the lines 52 times and print r (I do not know why - but ok), do the following

```
with open('simpletextfile.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for r in range(1, 52):
        for line in lines:
            print r
```

Furthermore, although you are only reading the file in this example (and Python will close it automatically for you), you should explicitly `.close()` it yourself or wrap it around a `with` statement as above, which will close it at the end - it is less sloppy.

Answer (score 4):

Because you can't read a text file twice. So on the first iteration, it reads the file and prints "1" as many times as they are lines in your file. When it goes to `r==2`, it tries to call `f.readlines()`, but as the file is already read, it stops the iteration before even starting it. And so on up to `r == 51`.

If you explain more what you're trying to do, we can maybe help more effectively.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `f.readlines()` for first time, it will return a list with one item: `['This a message!!']`. But when you call `f.readlines()` for the second time and so on it will return empty list `[]`. So, when you loop over it, it will not looping at all because the list is empty. Assign `f.readlines()` to variable to fix your problem

```
f = open("simpletextfile.txt")
for r in range(1,52):
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print r
```